# How to create a Windows Azure application hosted in different datacenters

Tags: windows, azure, storage, scalability

I'm trying to figure out how to scale a Windows Azure app, where there are some web roles and some worker roles.

The objective is to have some instances in a US datacenter and some others in an Europe datacenter, for different users in America an Europe to have the better response time. My problem is to replicate all my storages (for users in Europe who travel to America and viceversa) and even for troubles in one datacenter.

Until now, I understand that it's possible using [Traffic Manager](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/traffic-manager/) to let Azure know which datacenter is closer to the user.

I know I can replicate data between databases with [SQL Data Sync](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-data-sync/).

The blob storages can also be replicated using [Copy Blob API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) .

I understand the queues cannot be automatically replicated but I don't have much problem with that.

My problem is I cannot find a way to replicate table storages.

As a matter of fact I really don't know if this is the best strategy for my problem...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DX - you are right on with Traffic Manager and Data Sync.  Those are the best options for roles & SQL.  However, BLOBs are much easier - enable CDN and your BLOBs are replicated across 24 data centers automatically.  Read [Using CDN for Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/) for how to setup the CDN from your primary Storage account.

For table storage, I would handle this programatically, keep a list of the Table connections and then use a parallel foreach to insert into the different data centers.

We maintain a different Service Configuration file for each Data Center to simplify deployment.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your recomendations

Comment: if you need more config help - shoot me an email!